# Number of Integer Solutions Confusion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image: From Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics: An Applied Introduction]

So I understand that to solve $x_1 + \cdots + x_6 < 10$ you can solve for the number of solutions of $x_1 + \cdots +x_6 = 1$, $x_1 + \cdots +x_6 = 2$ etc. then just add it up. However I don't understand the method textbooks used. First of all I don't understand how Eq. (2) came about. So I don't understand the last paragraph of the example. Can someone explain it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same that you have exposed but in a different way. If you have to solve $$x_1+\ldots +x_6<10,$$ that is the same as solve $$x_1+\ldots +x_6=10-k$$ where $0<k\leq 10$ because if $k>10$ and $x_i\geq 0$ there is no solution and if $k\leq 0$ then $10-k\geq10$ and we do not want that either. So call $k=x_7$, then $$x_1+\ldots +x_6+k=x_1+\ldots +x_6+x_7=10$$ with the restriction for $k$.
Hope it helps.